# How to determine if a specific node finds all others?

Tags: c, search, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

So I'm trying to determine if I can find a specific node that can be used to find all other nodes inside a certain graph. I did somewhat psuedo code in C. I'm having trouble determining how I should check for the visited nodes when using Depth first Search.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int n;
int Graph[n][n];
int visited[n];

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i;
    int j;
    int x = 1;

    for (i=0; i < n; i++){ // run DFS on all variables to determine if any one node implies all others
        DFS(i) // starting node/variable

        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            if (visited[j]==0){ // has not been visited
                x = 0; // boolean int variable set to 0
            }
        }

        if (x!=0){ // if all variables are visited, x will be equal to 1
            printf("This variable implies all others");
            return i;
        }
    }
    printf("No variables imply all others");
    return -1;
}


int DFS(int i)
{
    int j;
    visited[i]=1;

    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
       if(!visited[j]&&G[i][j]==1){
            DFS(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in your code:

here you define another `x` inside `if clause`, which is completely different from the one you defined at the beginning of `main`.

```
if (visited[j]==0){ // has not been visited
    int x = 0; // boolean int variable set to 0
}
```

And, you also forgot to reset `visited` before every `DFS`.

Comment: oh wow i just realized that mistake, also how would i go about resetting visited? Do i have to use a for loop and set all the values back equal to 0 or is there an easier way i can do this?

Comment: @fatalwanderer using a for loop is easy enough

Answer (score 0):

As said on other answer your code is wrong. You don't set values for `visited[]` (and should reset them each loop). You return the node number in `main()` which is probably useless. Where you set `x = 0;` should should leave the loop (with `break`): no need to check other values. You shouldn't check G[i][j] if `i==j` (depending on your graph coding).

But why are you doing so complicated code? If I understand well you just looking for a node connected to all others. So `visited[]` is not usefull. Node `i` is connected to all other if none of `G[i][j]==0` for each `j`. It could be:

```
// returns true (1) if i connected, false (0) else
int DFS(int i) {
  int j;
  for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
    if ((j != i) && (G[i][j] == 0)) {
      return 0;  // we know it is not "complete"
    }
  }
  return 1; // not false -> true :)
}
```